# Testing variable against two values

Tags: php

I've this condition:

```
if( ($extension !== ".com") || ($extension !== ".fr") ) {
  unset($value);
} else {
  echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

I want to remove items from an array whose extensions are not ".com" or ".fr".
But every item in the array gets unset. I think my condition is wrong.

Here's the list items from the array:

> urltest.com
>   urltest.fr
>   url-testdeux.com
>   urltestthree.uk

Comment: you want and ($extension !== ".com") && ($extension !== ".fr") )

Comment: Post your full code. It'd make it a lot easier on us to help you.

Comment: You are indeed wrong with the condition. If you reverse it it reads something like if `$extension === ".com" && $extension === ".fr"` then `echo $value."<br/>"` which makes no sense since the extension can't be both .com and .fr

Answer (score 3):

You want to be using `&&` rather than `||` like this:-

```
if ($extension !== ".com" && $extension !== ".fr") {
}
```

Alternatively you could do:-

```
if (!in_array($extension, [".com", ".fr"])) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&`, not `||`.

`if (!a || !b)` will always succeed, because `$extension` cannot be two different values at the same time, so ONE of `!a` or `!b` will evaluate to true, making the whole expression true.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down what is happening with two examples: ".org" and ".com":

".org":

```
($extension !== ".com") || ($extension !== ".fr")
```

Will produce:

```
true || true
```

since both ".org" is not equal to both. this will work as expected.

Let's look at ".com". This will produce:

```
false || true
```

Your condition will only be false for items that are both ".com" and ".fr".

Instead you'll likely want to use `&&`.

Even better is to reverse the logic to make it clearer:

```
    if( ($extension === ".com") || ($extension === ".fr") ) {
        echo $value.'<br>';
    } else {
        unset($value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using || excludes both .com and .fr. Since only one part of the statement has to be true to pass .uk is not .com, so the statement would be true, but .com is not .fr so the statement would be true again.  The && operator means that both requirements have to be passed. Since .com is not .fr, one of the tests fails the statement will fail. Since .uk is neither .com nor .fr, it will evaluate as true.

```
(($extension !== ".com") && ($extension !== ".fr"))
```

or if you want to use ||, you can switch your true and false statements:

```
if( ($extension !== ".com") || ($extension !== ".fr") ) {
       echo $value.'<br>';
  } else {
         unset($value);
  }
```